# Phrases to differ respectfully

Tags: phrases, expressions, formality, politeness

If I were to disagree with an opinion, how should I write it in a respectful and idiomatic way?

Normally I would write;

> "Tinged with regret, I respectfully disagree."

Are there any other phrases or expressions to differ in opinion?

Comment: "Tinged with regret" is not idiomatic.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I have to disagree with you.

Comment: I see it differently...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***"With all due respect, I (regretfully) disagree."***

***With all due respect***

> used as a polite formula preceding, and intended to mitigate the effect of, an expression of disagreement or criticism.

[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/with_all_due_respect)

*I (regretfully) disagree*...

is standard English where "regretfully" is probably redundant. But some cultures require that.